# How to change the initial values of array while using useFormik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Here is the code where I am using useFormik hook

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    name: '',
    status: 'new',
    functionalBreakdown: [],
    spatialBreakdown: [],
    form: [],
    discipline: [],
    companyId,
  },
  validate,
  onSubmit: async (values) => {
    try {
      // const res = await
      setFormData(values);
    } catch (error) {}
  },
});
```

How can I update the array? Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: Which array? What have you tried? Can you let us know your current error and desired result?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904217/useformik-cause-too-many-re-renders

Comment: Try this answer, might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70904294/7096256

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to manually update a formik value you would use e.g.

```
formik.setFieldValue(name, "John Doe");
```

If you have list values you would probably use a multi select like in this sandbox:

[image: Edit formik & react-select multi (Typescript) (forked)]

> **Note:** If you want to update your `initialValues` upon first initialization for example through changing props or states you need to pass `enableReinitialize: true` to useFormik hook.